# sed replace text within a sequence of parentheses (oracle connection string)

Tags: regex, sed

I have this text string within a configuration file:

```
jdbcService.oraclePool.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=oracleserver.example.com)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=oracleserver55)))
```

I'd like to replace with sed the value "(HOST=oracleserver.example.com)" without sticking to the text after the = symbol.
I tried to use several regexp but cannot find the working one:

```
# sed 's/\((HOST=.*?)\)/(HOST=newvalue)/' customer_overrides.properties
jdbcService.oraclePool.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=oracleserver.example.com)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=oracleserver55)))

# sed -E 's/\((HOST=.*?)\)/(HOST=newvalue)/' customer_overrides.properties | grep HOST=
jdbcService.oraclePool.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=newvalue)

# sed 's/\((HOST=.*[^)])\)/(HOST=newvalue)/' customer_overrides.properties | grep HOST=
jdbcService.oraclePool.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=newvalue)))
```

I am working on:

- linux RH7
- sed-4.2.2-5.el7.x86_64

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed 's/HOST=[^)]*/HOST=foobar/' file
```

Output:

```
jdbcService.oraclePool.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=foobar)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=oracleserver55)))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to stick to sed this is a good alternative:

```
perl -pi -e 's/\((HOST=.*?)\)/(HOST=foobar)/g' customer_overrides.properties
```

But I prefer Cyrus' reply :)